# How to send Requests from Magento Soap Api to Firebase cloud messaging?

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

How to send notifications created in magento to Firebase Cloud messaging using soap API. Is there any curl method needs to be created for the message needs to be pushed into the Firebase like the below

> curl -X POST -d '{"user_id" : "jack", "text" : "test!", "message": "Hello world"}'  'https://.firebaseio.com/message_list.json'

Please any help of this point? Thanks

Comment: I have fixed this issue by adding curl code in my custom module